# Compare suppliers' bids | Excel | Conditional formatting | Color scales

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to compare suppliers' bids using 3 colors scale as share in a picture

Bid comparison:
[image]

Usually I have 100+ rows.
Any idea how to do it with formatting?
If not, what is the code in VBA to be used?
Thanks,
Mateusz

Comment: Use conditional formatting and a formula, I would use the small() function as in green for the smallest in the range etc

Comment: I don't understand the issue with your question. This looks just like a very basic 3 color scale of Excel's Conditional Formatting feature: [Highlight patterns and trends with conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/highlight-patterns-and-trends-with-conditional-formatting-eea152f5-2a7d-4c1a-a2da-c5f893adb621). No need of VBA or formulas at all, just use the built in feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formating. First highlight the item's row. Then click `Home>Styles>Conditional Formatting>Color Scales` (Circled in Red) and then whatever scale you find most astectically pleasing.

You can then copy that formatting down the rows by highlighting the first row, then go to `Home>Clipboard>Format Painter` (Circled in Blue then select the rest of the range you want that formatting to apply to. The formating should adapt to each item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mark your values and select conditional formating.

[image]

Comment: You chose the correct tool but you should do that per item to get what the OP was looking for. If you do it for all items at once you will get the global maximum…minimum number in red…green, but according to his screenshot he's looking for the maximum…minimum number per item.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize. Uppdated the picture accordingly